# Switching position of 3 divs in jquery

Tags: jquery

i have a exercise for school where i have to position the first block with class 'pullquote' left then when the loop goes for the second time i need to position the second block with class 'pullquote' right and then the 3th time the last block needs to position to the left.

Here is what i have already:

```
$('span.pq').each(function ()
    {

        //Clone om het bij alle span pq te doen
        var quote = $(this).clone();
        quote.removeClass('pq');
        quote.addClass('pullquote');
        $(this).before(quote);

        $('.pullquote').css('float', 'left');

    }); // end each
```

But the problem is they position all left now

Answer (score 1):

Use the `:odd` and `:even` pseudo-selectors.

#### SNIPPET

```js
$('div:odd').addClass('pullquote left');
$('div:even').addClass('pullquote right');
```

```css
.pullquote {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 3em;
  height: 1em;
  }
.right {
  float: right;
  background: rgba(255,0,0,.5);
  }
.left {
  float: left;
  background: rgba(0,255,0,.5);
  }
.right:before { content: 'RIGHT'; }
.left:before { content: 'LEFT'; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```